# Values in a variable need to be assigned 1:1 like in an array, but not working

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

Let us assume, I do have a varying number of values stored in a variable (called `MY_VARIABLE`). The first ones are i.e.: 12345 67890 ...

I now would like to go through this list of values and assign them `1:1` to an array-based variable like following:

```
MY_ARRAY[0]=12345   
MY_ARRAY[1]=67890
...
```

How can this be achieved?

Please note: When trying it with a loop it fails as `MY_ARRAY[0]` shows **all** values (12345, 67890, ...) inside.

My bash version: GNU bash, version 3.2.39(1)-release (i486-pc-linux-gnu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
MY_ARRAY=( $MY_VARIABLE )
```

Will separate the values separated by spaces into MY_ARRAY with beginning index at 0.

You view array values with:

```
${MY_ARRAY[0]} ${MY_ARRAY[1]) etc...
```

Viewing all values in array at once with:

```
${MY_ARRAY[@]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `read -a`:

```
MY_VARIABLE='12345 67890'
read -a arr <<< "$MY_VARIABLE"
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
12345
67890
```